# Angularjs clear multiple filters on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have multiple filters from various select boxes on a page.  My ideal functionality is to give the user the option to reset all the filters with a single button click.  I'm able to achieve this individually with select boxes to reset that particular filter but not multiple filters at once.

Here is the code -

```
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="typeFilter">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <option>Stock</option>
                                        <option>Special Order</option>
                                        <option>Part</option>
                                    </select>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">  
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="itemStatus">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <option>Active</option>
                                        <option>Discontinued</option>
                                        <option>Obsolete</option>
                                        <option>Deleted</option>
                                    </select>                                                                              
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large button-dropdown" data-translate="Rest_Filters" ng-click="vm.clearFilter()"> Rest Filters</button>
                                </div>
```

Controllers of what I've tried -

```
    vm.clearFilter = function () {
    vm.typeFilter = {};
    vm.typeFilter = "";
    vm.typeFilter = null;

    vm.itemStatus = {};
    vm.itemStatus = "";
    vm.itemStatus = null;
}
```

I've also tried inline syntax such as

```
 ng-click="typeFilter = null"
 ng-click="typeFilter = {}"
```

and a few others but nothing seems to clear the filter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's something with your pointer variable

```
  $scope.clearFilter = function() {
    $scope.typeFilter = null;
    $scope.itemStatus = null;
  }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/eRw7L6c8Cd84oLUUDnQm?p=preview